# wso2 api analytics schema

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have installed wso2 APIManager and APIAnalytics,I want to change the APIANalytics datasource from h2 to mysql

In the tutorial they mentioned to create the equivalent database schema for WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB

Where can I find the schemas for the database

Thanks

Comment: which tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prabhat
You need to perform following steps to configure your wso2-am-analytics on mysql.

**step 1**. create all required databases in mysql db. just create it nothing else

- create database wso2am_stats_db; --use existing one of wso2-am
- create database wso2metrics_db; --use existing one of wso2-am
- create database wso2_processed_data_store;
- create database wso2carbon_db;
- create database wso2_geolocation_db;
- create database wso2_event_store;

**step 2**: configure these database in configuraton files under /wso2am-analytics-2.0.0/repository/conf/datasources/. there are 5 of them which you need to edit and change the database details.

- analytics-datasources.xml
- geolocation-datasources.xml
- master-datasources.xml
- metrics-datasources.xml
- stats-datasources.xml

**Step 3 :**
once you are done, then start your server with -Dsetup (only once) this will create all tables needed. for example: **sh bin/wso2server.sh -Dsetup**

fore more read this article: [Setting up MySQL](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Setting+up+MySQL)